# 4th order tensor rotation - sources to refer

Tags: reference-request, solid-mechanics, tensor

I am trying to model a linear elastic material in Abaqus using a UMAT. For my application, I need to rotate the 6x6 compliance matrix for a given set of eigenvectors (or a rotation matrix). I came across a thread titled ["debugging a rotation matrix for elastic constants"](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/debugging-a-rotation-matrix-for-elastic-constants) where this theory was explained in very good detail.

I was wondering if there are any good sources out there that show the actual matrix rotation process either in a computational sense or just a theoretical representation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two main ways to write stress/strain tensors as 6 components vectors:

- Voigt notation, that is the most common; and
- Mandel-Kelvin notation, that has the advantage of writing stress and strains in the same way, so their rotations are done via the same $6\times 6$ matrices.

A reference that I consider good for Voigt's notation is Auld's book (Vol. 1, Ch. 3, D) and Mehrabadi and Cowin's paper describes the rotation matrix for Mandel-Kelvin notation. In general, I would suggest that you use a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) for your calculation since they can get long really fast. I developed [a Python package](https://github.com/nicoguaro/continuum_mechanics) and the developing version has these matrices in there.

### References

- Auld, B. A. (1973). Acoustic fields and waves in solids. Рипол Классик.
- Bower, Allan F. [Applied Mechanics of Solids](http://solidmechanics.org/Text/Chapter3_2/Chapter3_2.php). CRC press, 2009.
  Ch. 3.
- Carcione, J. M. (2007). Wave fields in real media: Wave propagation in anisotropic, anelastic, porous and electromagnetic media. Elsevier.
- Mehrabadi, Morteza M., Stephen C. Cowin. 1990. “Eigentensors of Linear Anisotropic Elastic Materials”. The Quarterly Journal of Mechanics and Applied Mathematics 43(1):15–41.

---

Suppose that you have a rotation matrix

$$[Q] = \begin{bmatrix}
Q_{xx} &Q_{xy} &Q_{xz}\\
Q_{yx} &Q_{yy} &Q_{yz}\\
Q_{zx} &Q_{zy} &Q_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\, ,$$

and you are using the following Voigt notation order: $xx$, $yy$, $zz$, $yz$, $xz$, $xy$.

You can form the (Bond-like) rotation matrices that are described below.

### Voigt notation

#### Rotation of stresses

$$[M] =\begin{bmatrix}
Q_{xx}^{2} & Q_{xy}^{2} & Q_{xz}^{2} &
2 Q_{xy} Q_{xz} & 2 Q_{xx} Q_{xz} & 2 Q_{xx} Q_{xy}\\
Q_{yx}^{2} & Q_{yy}^{2} & Q_{yz}^{2} & 2 Q_{yy} Q_{yz} &
2 Q_{yx} Q_{yz} & 2 Q_{yx} Q_{yy}\\
Q_{zx}^{2} & Q_{zy}^{2} & Q_{zz}^{2} & 2 Q_{zy} Q_{zz} &
2 Q_{zx} Q_{zz} & 2 Q_{zx} Q_{zy}\\
Q_{yx} Q_{zx} & Q_{yy} Q_{zy} & Q_{yz} Q_{zz} & Q_{yy}
Q_{zz} + Q_{yz} Q_{zy} & Q_{yx} Q_{zz} + Q_{yz} Q_{zx}
& Q_{yx} Q_{zy} + Q_{yy} Q_{zx}\\
Q_{xx} Q_{zx} & Q_{xy} Q_{zy} & Q_{xz} Q_{zz} & Q_{xy}
Q_{zz} + Q_{xz} Q_{zy} & Q_{xx} Q_{zz} + Q_{xz} Q_{zx}
& Q_{xx} Q_{zy} + Q_{xy} Q_{zx}\\
Q_{xx} Q_{yx} & Q_{xy} Q_{yy} & Q_{xz} Q_{yz} & Q_{xy}
Q_{yz} + Q_{xz} Q_{yy} & Q_{xx} Q_{yz} + Q_{xz} Q_{yx}
& Q_{xx} Q_{yy} + Q_{xy} Q_{yx}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The rotation of a stiffness tensor in Voigt's notation is done via

$$[C'] = [M] [C] [M^T]\, .$$

#### Rotation of strains

$$[N] =
\begin{bmatrix}Q_{xx}^{2} & Q_{xy}^{2} & Q_{xz}^{2} &
Q_{xy} Q_{xz} & Q_{xx} Q_{xz} & Q_{xx} Q_{xy}\\
Q_{yx}^{2} & Q_{yy}^{2} & Q_{yz}^{2} & Q_{yy} Q_{yz} &
Q_{yx} Q_{yz} & Q_{yx} Q_{yy}\\
Q_{zx}^{2} & Q_{zy}^{2} & Q_{zz}^{2} & Q_{zy} Q_{zz} &
Q_{zx} Q_{zz} & Q_{zx} Q_{zy}\\
2 Q_{yx} Q_{zx} & 2 Q_{yy} Q_{zy} & 2 Q_{yz} Q_{zz} &
Q_{yy} Q_{zz} + Q_{yz} Q_{zy} & Q_{yx} Q_{zz} +
Q_{yz} Q_{zx} & Q_{yx} Q_{zy} + Q_{yy} Q_{zx}\\
2 Q_{xx} Q_{zx} & 2 Q_{xy} Q_{zy} & 2 Q_{xz} Q_{zz} &
Q_{xy} Q_{zz} + Q_{xz} Q_{zy} & Q_{xx} Q_{zz} +
Q_{xz} Q_{zx} & Q_{xx} Q_{zy} + Q_{xy} Q_{zx}\\
2 Q_{xx} Q_{yx} & 2 Q_{xy} Q_{yy} & 2 Q_{xz} Q_{yz} &
Q_{xy} Q_{yz} + Q_{xz} Q_{yy} & Q_{xx} Q_{yz} +
Q_{xz} Q_{yx} & Q_{xx} Q_{yy} + Q_{xy} Q_{yx}
\end{bmatrix}$$

The rotation of a compliance tensor in Voigt's notation is done via

$$[C'] = [N] [C] [N^T]\, .$$

### Mandel-Kelvin notation

$$[M] = \begin{bmatrix}
Q_{xx}^{2} & Q_{xy}^{2} & Q_{xz}^{2} &
\sqrt{2} Q_{xy} Q_{xz} & \sqrt{2} Q_{xx} Q_{xz} & \sqrt{2} Q_{xx} Q_{xy}\\
Q_{yx}^{2} & Q_{yy}^{2} & Q_{yz}^{2} & \sqrt{2} Q_{yy} Q_{yz} &
\sqrt{2} Q_{yx} Q_{yz} & \sqrt{2} Q_{yx} Q_{yy}\\
Q_{zx}^{2} & Q_{zy}^{2} & Q_{zz}^{2} & \sqrt{2} Q_{zy} Q_{zz} &
\sqrt{2} Q_{zx} Q_{zz} & \sqrt{2} Q_{zx} Q_{zy}\\
\sqrt{2}Q_{yx} Q_{zx} & \sqrt{2}Q_{yy} Q_{zy} & \sqrt{2}Q_{yz} Q_{zz}
& Q_{yy}Q_{zz} + Q_{yz} Q_{zy} & Q_{yx} Q_{zz} + Q_{yz} Q_{zx}
& Q_{yx} Q_{zy} + Q_{yy} Q_{zx}\\
\sqrt{2}Q_{xx} Q_{zx} & \sqrt{2}Q_{xy} Q_{zy} & \sqrt{2}Q_{xz} Q_{zz}
& Q_{xy}Q_{zz} + Q_{xz} Q_{zy} & Q_{xx} Q_{zz} + Q_{xz} Q_{zx}
& Q_{xx} Q_{zy} + Q_{xy} Q_{zx}\\
\sqrt{2}Q_{xx} Q_{yx} & \sqrt{2}Q_{xy} Q_{yy} & \sqrt{2}Q_{xz} Q_{yz}
& Q_{xy} Q_{yz} + Q_{xz} Q_{yy} & Q_{xx} Q_{yz} + Q_{xz} Q_{yx}
& Q_{xx} Q_{yy} + Q_{xy} Q_{yx}
\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case, you can rotate stiffness and compliance tensors with

$$[A'] = [M] [A] [M^T]\, .$$